# How to print out a specific String from a text file

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to figure out a way to print out *specific* Strings from a .txt file.

Here is my method:

```
public static void writeBirdtype() {

In innSkjerm = new In(); // Reading from terminal
In fil = new In("fugler.txt"); // Reading from file   

System.out.println("Write out all the observations of a birdtype: ");
String ord = innSkjerm.readLine();

System.out.println("All the observations you asked for:");
while (fil.hasNext()) {
String linje = fil.inWord();
System.out.println(linje);

} // end of while-statement              

} // end of writeBirdType() method
```

The problem is this code prints out *all* the Strings from a .txt file, which is not what i'm trying to accomplish. Can anyone see what I am missing here? Thank you.

Comment: How do you determine which String you want?

Comment: Probably some `if`...

Comment: Did you consider regular expressions or `grep`?

Comment: This is almost an exact duplicate of a question you posted a few hours ago that has since been removed. I don't see any new content here...

Comment: im using a library called easyIO, not sure if you guys are so familiar with it. But i'm trying to accomplish if the user inputs the String "Craw" the output should print out all the Strings from file called "Craw".

Comment: @RobertH Yes, there is new content here. I added while statement :)

Comment: Well, print `linje` only `if` it contains `ord`. Read javadoc of string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of how to read something (string in this case) from a file

```
private String readFileAsString(String filePath) throws IOException {
    StringBuffer fileData = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
       new FileReader(filePath));
       char[] buf = new char[1024];
       int numRead=0;

        while((numRead=reader.read(buf)) != -1){
            String readData = String.valueOf(buf, 0, numRead);
            fileData.append(readData);
        }
        reader.close();
        return fileData.toString();
   }
   //rest implementation
```

edit:  this solution will be better for you as it will be easier to understand

You can modify it in a way to read whatever you want. This should do you for now.

Comment: thanks alot for your help, I would rate it if i had enough reputation :)